# What does declaring optional function input to nil in Swift do?

Tags: ios, swift

I have had trouble understanding why the data is set to nil in input ? How does this affect the function inputs

`public init(description: String, data: [Data]? = nil)`

Comment: This is clearly explained in the Swift programming language guide. I strongly suggest *all* swift devs read it, cover to cover. It's basically non-optional, because otherwise you just waste your time googling basics like this. It's much faster to just read it once and for all https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID166

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function parameter `data` has a default parameter, so while using `init` you could leave `data` and it would assume `nil` as the value. Summing up you could use the `init` either as

```
init(description: <#T##String#>)
```

or like:

```
init(description: <#T##String#>, data: <#T##[Data]?#>)
```